# SQL Server - How to only join when other attribute between select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to work up a query to show a students attendance records. These are my tables.

[image]

This is what I have started so far...

I am matching a list of studentId's (StudentCalendar) to days school was open (DateCollection) then to records of missed days (Attendance).

I end up with something like this..

```
 SELECT s.personid,
        dc.calendarid, 
        dc.[date], 
        coalesce(absentMinutes,0) AS absentMinutes
   FROM [dbo].[StudentCalendar] s
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DateCollection] dc ON s.calendarId = dc.calendarId
         LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Attendance] a ON a.dateOccurred = dc.[date]
               AND a.personId = s.personId
```

[image]

I now have a list of students with every day school was open. 
My problem is that not every student was signed up for the full school year.

Is there a way for me to only match the list of studentid's (StudentCalendar) with days school was open (DateCollection) when it's within the range given in a students calendar startDate & endDate (Calendar) for each student?

something like this..

[image]

Comment: Why can't more people ask questions like this?  Listing table structure, check.  Listing what's been tried, check.  Listing current result vs desired result, check.  Okay, no starting dataset, but relationships are clear (for future questions, note that we prefer starting datasets be listed as text, for inclusion in testing).  +1  .  As a side note, `DateCollection` and `Calendar` are somewhat misleadingly named.  If you're trying to enable storage of attendance for more than one school, you'll need to change the design of the rest of the tables as well.

Comment: Have you tried a simple (inner) JOIN between your current result set and the StudentCalendar table? If you join on the personid and date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate, you should be good.

Comment: +1. Just a note: It's excellent when you include all the info you have in your question (as @Clockwork-Muse points out), it would be much better if you did so in text rather than in images. The images make it difficult to read in a mobile device, require excessive data downloads (still an issue for some users here), and often get blocked by corporate proxy servers, making the question impossible to read. It's much better to only use images as a last resort when nothing else will work to get your point across.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments on my question structure. I've had a plenty of question deleted or removed (which is very frustrating) because I was not clear enough. glad to here i've at least got that down now (except images). :-)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT s.personid,
    dc.calendarid, 
    dc.[date], 
    coalesce(absentMinutes,0) AS absentMinutes
FROM [dbo].[StudentCalendar] s
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DateCollection] dc ON s.calendarId = dc.calendarId
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Attendance] a ON a.dateOccurred = dc.[date]
           AND a.personId = s.personId
           AND dc.[date] BETWEEN s.startDate AND isnull(s.endDate,'99991231')
```

Comment: The INNER JOIN seems to remove some of the needed dates. I've update below with a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from Frazz. I seem to have found an answer..

I added additional conditions to the JOIN ON clause as well as a CASE statment to deal with NULL values in my endDate

```
SELECT s.personid,
        dc.calendarid, 
        dc.[date],
        COALESCE(absentMinutes,0) AS absentMinutes
  FROM [dbo].[StudentCalendar] s 
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DateCollection] dc ON s.calendarId=dc.calendarId 
                AND dc.[date] >= s.startDate 
                AND dc.[date] <= (CASE 
                                        WHEN s.endDate is null 
                                        THEN (SELECT c.endDate FROM Calendar c WHERE c.calendarId=s.calendarId) 
                                        ELSE s.endDate 
                                  END)
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Attendance] a ON a.dateOccurred=dc.[date] AND a.personId=s.personId
```

Alternatively, this works as well.

```
SELECT s.personid,
        dc.calendarid, 
        dc.[date],
        COALESCE(absentMinutes,0) AS absentMinutes, 
  FROM [dbo].[StudentCalendar] s 
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DateCollection] dc 
                ON s.calendarId=dc.calendarId AND dc.[date] BETWEEN s.startDate AND ISNULL(s.endDate,'99991231')
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Attendance] a 
                ON a.dateOccurred=dc.[date] AND a.personId=s.personId
```

Comment: As a side note, you should [avoid inclusive upper bounds](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (`<=`) with positive contiuous-range types. SQL Server just has a few extra gotchas due to some types. This may be important if the `absence` information begins to include the start of the time the student was absent. For performance reasons you may be better off joining to `calendar` regardless, and doing the comparisons as regular boolean conditions - optimizers tend to dislike `CASE` subqueries.